# Node Js SHA 1 multiple times

Tags: node.js, cryptography, sha1

Hello I have this Java code which uses the following encryption method to encrypt password.

```
 MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
 value = digester.digest(password.getBytes());
 digester.update(email.getBytes());
 value = digester.digest(value);
```

This returns base64 encoded string like `qXO4aUUUyiue6arrcLAio+TBNwQ=` This is sample not exact.

I am converting this to NodeJs not sure how to handle this. I have tried like

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1'); 
var value = shasum.update('hello'); 
shasum.update('abc@xyz.com'); 
value = shasum.digest(value).toString('base64'); 
console.log(value);
```

The string base64 I get in node js is not similar to get from java. Not sure why?. I need to have same encoding as java as its old system migrated to new one cant lose old details.

Can someone help me how I can achieve same base64 string.

Comment: In any case, SHA-1 is an awful idea for password hashing. It's a weak fast hash, not a password hash. Use Bcrypt at least.

Comment: Yes I know I cant change because the old users to be migrated are registered with this method and cant loose those. thats why I need to keep this method

Comment: In the java code you seem to be doing the following: Compute the digest of password, update the digester with email , then compute the final digest. The final digest here is actually - digest of (digest of password+email). In your node.js code it is  - digest of(password+email). Did you notice that or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

In Java you're calculating the first value as the hash of the password alone, then overwrite it with hash of the email alone. (`digest` gives the result and resets the hash, in Java).

In Javascript, on the other hand, you're having an `undefined` value, then overwrite it with the hash of (password concatenated with email).

PS that hash is conceptually wrong: you should always put a separator between two fields, to avoid ambiguity and, thus, possible attacks.